# Cmake not set make program

Tags: cmake, makefile, cross-compiling

I use cross gcc for armv7hf on Windows 10

When I try to build a project using cmake I get an error
`CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: -f Makefile`

In the toolchain i wrote SET(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM %path_to_toolchain%)

I looked at CMakeCache and noticed that there is no CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM there, but if you set it, everything works.
Tell me please, how can I force CMake to set the correct values in the cache?
I use this command to build `cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=c:/test/toolchain.cmake -G"Unix Makefiles"`

Comment: `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` rightly belongs to the generator, not the toolchain.  The toolchain file is an inappropriate place to set it.  That does not necessarily mean that setting it in the toolchain file could not work, but I observe that you are setting it as a normal variable, not a cache variable.  You could change the `SET()` call to make it set a cache variable, but I would recommend instead just defining it on the `cmake` command line.